# Partial Rendering of another controller's view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, view, partial-views

I am using twitter Boostraps tabbable feature found here:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

And within this navigation content window, I am trying to render a view that displays a "course". This view found in views/courses/_show.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
<h1><%= @course.course_name %></h1>

<%= link_to 'New Question Set',new_answer_path(:course_ID => @course.id), :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to 'Launch Session!', edit_course_path, :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

I am trying to render it and failing with the following code in views/instructor/show.html.erb

```
<% courses.each do |c| %>
<div class="tab-pane" id="<%=c.course_name%>">
<%= render :partial => 'courses/show', :locals => {@course=>c} %>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

> /app/views/courses/_show.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected '=',
>   expecting keyword_end ...tput_buffer = @output_buffer; =
>   local_assigns[:];show = loca... ...                               ^
>   /app/views/courses/_show.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected ']',
>   expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or
>   tSTRING_END ...tput_buffer; = local_assigns[:];show =
>   local_assigns[:show];... ...

saying it's failing at line 1 of my courses/_show.html.erb

My Course Controller looks like this:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /courses
  # GET /courses.json
  def index
    @courses = Course.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @courses }
    end
  end

  # GET /courses/1
  # GET /courses/1.json
  def show
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @course }
    end
  end

  # GET /courses/new
  # GET /courses/new.json
  def new
    @course = Course.new(instructor_ID: params[:instructor_ID])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @course }
    end
  end

  # GET /courses/1/edit
  def edit
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /courses
  # POST /courses.json
  def create
    @course = Course.new(params[:course])


    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.save
        format.html { redirect_to @course, :notice => 'Course was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @course, :status => :created, :location => @course }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @course.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /courses/1
  # PUT /courses/1.json
  def update
    @course = Course.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @course.update_attributes(params[:course])
        format.html { redirect_to @course, :notice => 'Course was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @course.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Note: I have ommited some of the methods like delete in my controller to save space.

Any Ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `@course=>c` change the @ to a colon.

Comment: when I do that I get an error that looks like: undefined method 'course_name' for nil:NilClass that fails at line 2 of the page I'm trying to render